# How do you access an instance variable in an Authlogic config block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authlogic

Given a user model something along the lines of:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.validate_email_field = true
  end

end
```

I would like to be able to modify "true" to be specific to the user that is signing up. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.validate_email_field = ['dont@validate.me'].include?(instance_email)
  end

end
```

but instance_email isn't available there. Do you have to override a method on the user model in order to access this variable? How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because the Authlogic block is evaluated when the class is loaded and it has no instance context.

You need to write your own validator.

```
class User < ...

  validate :validate_email

  ...

  def validate_email
    if !['dont@validate.me'].include?(instance_email)
      # write here your validation logic
    end
  end 

end
```